# alguien puede sabe como hacer con esta parte de mi todolist?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Yo estoy haciendo un `to-do-list` con **HTML** y **JS** y quiero que una de mis funciones, con una especie de `checkbox`, al apretarlo imprima en consola "**yes**" en principal pero nose como hacerlo con mi código.Yo he estado intentando al agregar un `input:checkbox` pero no puedo hacer que lo lea cuando apreto y sale el tilde. Yen mi código como verán he creado elementos con **JS** pero no se puede crear un `input` de tipo `checkbox`.

Disculpen la pregunta es que soy nuevo programando y este es mi primer proyecto.

**JS**

```js
const list= document.getElementById("list");
const input= document.getElementById("input");


let toDo=[];
let buttonToDo=[];
let id;
let idButton;



function addToDo(itemValue,id,idButton){
    
    itemValue= input.value;
    const itemNew= document.createElement("li");
   const deleteButton= document.createElement("button");
    const text= `
                    <p class="text">${itemValue}</p>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="check">
                    
                `;
    itemNew.classList.add("item");           
    itemNew.innerHTML=text;
    list.appendChild(itemNew)
    
    toDo.push(itemNew)
    id= toDo.indexOf(itemNew)
    console.log(id)
    
    deleteButton.classList.add("delete");
    deleteButton.value="REMOVE"
    itemNew.appendChild(deleteButton);

    buttonToDo.push(deleteButton);
    idButton= buttonToDo.indexOf(deleteButton);

    deleteButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        if(idButton===id){
        list.removeChild(itemNew);
        }
    })

}

document.addEventListener("keyup",(event)=>{ if(event.keyCode===13){addToDo()}});


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    
    <title>To Do List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="clear">
                <i class="refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <div id="date"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <ul id="list">
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="add-item">
            <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Add Something to Do">
            <button type="submit" id="button" onclick="addToDo()">Click Me</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

No se puede acceder directamente a un elemento creado dinámicamente con javascript, debes agregar el evento al documento o a un elemento padre estático.
*En mi ejemplo uso jQuery, agregué el código necesario al final, luego de tu código.*

```js
const list= document.getElementById("list");
const input= document.getElementById("input");


let toDo=[];
let buttonToDo=[];
let id;
let idButton;



function addToDo(itemValue,id,idButton){
    
    itemValue= input.value;
    const itemNew= document.createElement("li");
   const deleteButton= document.createElement("button");
    const text= `
                    <p class="text">${itemValue}</p>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="check">
                    
                `;
    itemNew.classList.add("item");           
    itemNew.innerHTML=text;
    list.appendChild(itemNew)
    
    toDo.push(itemNew)
    id= toDo.indexOf(itemNew)
    console.log(id)
    
    deleteButton.classList.add("delete");
    deleteButton.value="REMOVE"
    itemNew.appendChild(deleteButton);

    buttonToDo.push(deleteButton);
    idButton= buttonToDo.indexOf(deleteButton);

    deleteButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        if(idButton===id){
        list.removeChild(itemNew);
        }
    })

}

document.addEventListener("keyup",(event)=>{ if(event.keyCode===13){addToDo()}});


//CÓDIGO NUEVO

$(document).on('click', ':checkbox', function(){
  console.log('Yes');
});





<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    
    <title>To Do List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="clear">
                <i class="refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <div id="date"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <ul id="list">
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="add-item">
            <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Add Something to Do">
            <button type="submit" id="button" onclick="addToDo()">Click Me</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```